# What is the object of this sentence?

Tags: objects, intransitive-verbs

In *Modern Family* (S06E05), the following sentence is spoken:

> Lily's parents were wrong about Mrs. Plank.

What is the object of this sentence?

Is Mrs. Plank the object - because Mrs. Plank is the receiver of the action?
Or does this sentence not have an object; instead, is the word "wrong" just an intransitive verb?
Or is it something else entirely...?

Comment: What is your partner's reasoning? (You're right, but I'm not sure why your partner got this wrong.)

Comment: The only object is "Mrs Plank", which is object of the preposition "about". There is no direct or indirect object. Note that the verb "be" is always intransitive, and "wrong" is an adjective, not a verb.

Comment: @JohnSmith It seems that on a semantic level you're understanding "were wrong about" to be synonymous with "misjudged", and then extrapolating from that semantic similarity that two sentences would have the same syntax when they differ only in that one respect ("were wrong about" vs "misjudged").

Answer (score 4):

The main clause has three elements:

> Lily's parents - subject (noun phrase)
>
> were - predicator (verb)
>
> wrong about Mrs. Plank - subject-oriented predicative complement
> (adjective phrase)

The adjective phrase can be further broken down into

> wrong - head (adjective)
>
> about Mrs. Plank - complement (preposition phrase)

The prepostion phrase can be further broken down into

> about - head (preposition)
>
> Mrs. Plank - complement: object (noun phrase)

So, there is an object in the sentence, however it does not have a function in the structure of the main clause; rather is has the function 'object' in the preposition phrase that is complement to 'wrong'.